# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 502 Error: Bad Gateway in JAX-WS

Tags: java, playframework, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have a system that consumes web services, I am using JAX-WS for consume that services, the system sometimes generated me the following exception:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 502 Error: Bad Gateway

Which is the reason why an exception Axis when I am using JAX-WS.

My system is developed in Play Framework.

Comment: Are you consuming the web service through proxy?